# Flask : Storing , Get and Update List in session using flask_session

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-session

I have been trying for a couple of days, but I have had no success using a session to store the list( e.g., list of notes).

Below is the code that I have written. It store 2 variables successfully and when I try adding the third variable to the list , it overrides the second variable instead of appending to the list

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "some_random"
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT']= False

Session(app)

@app.route("/notes", methods=["GET","POST"])
def addNotes():
    if 'notes' not in session:
        session['notes'] = []
    if request.method == "POST":
        note=request.form.get("note")
        notes_list = session['notes']
        notes_list.append(note)
        session['notes'] = notes_list
 
    
    return render_template("notes.html", notes=session['notes'])
```

notes.html :

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block heading %}
    Sticky Notes
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    
    <ul>
        {% for note in notes %}
            <li>{{ note }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <form action="{{ url_for('addNotes') }}" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="note" placeholder="Enter a note here">
        <button>Add Note</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Please suggest if there is any way to store, get and update the list variable stored in the session object.

I have tried using session.modification=True also, which was based on some suggestions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route("/notes", methods=["GET","POST"])
def addNotes():
    if request.method == "POST":
        note = request.form.get("note")
        if 'notes' in session:
            session['notes'].extend([note])
        else:
            session['notes'] = [note]
```

This works for me. But I mostly use sessions to store list of dicts.

Since you are storing your notes in the session, you don't have to pass it in the render template. You can directly access the session object in Jinja

```
<ul>
    {% if session['notes'] %}
    {% for note in session['notes'] %}
        <li>{{ note }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Your answer seemed perfect for me, until I had to spend an hour trying to debug a dumb mistake from it. In your answer, you've written `session['notes'] = session['notes'].extend([notes])`
The problem here is, `extend()` and `append()` are in-place functions. They return a value of `None` every time. You have to remove the `session['notes'] = ` part from the code and it works perfectly.